# Two definitions of smoothness?

Tags: schemes, ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

This is confusing, there appear to be possibly two definitions of smoothness in algebraic geometry for a morphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$ of schemes of finite type over an arbitrary field $k$.

Definition 1 (Milne, Etale Cohomology pp.30-31): Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be locally of finite type. Then we say $f$ is smooth if it is flat and $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is locally free of rank the relative dimension. (For reference, this is the same definition as in the stacks project.)

Definition 2: (Hartshorne, III.10, p268). A morphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$ of schemes of finite type over a field $k$ is smooth of relative dimension $n$ if it is flat, the sheaf of relative differentials $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is locally free of rank $n$, and if: (*) If $X' \subset X$ and $Y' \subset Y$ are irreducible components such that $f(X') \subset Y'$ then $\dim X' = \dim Y' + n$.

In the situation of Hartshorne's definition, there is the extra hypothesis (*). Is this always satisfied, or are there just two definitions?

Comment: I think that Hartshorne is just including the definition of "relative dimension $n$" in his version.  Milne says "of the relative dimension" so presumably he's assuming the reader knows what that means already.

Comment: There are several different definitions for smoothness, some of which are equivalent and some of which are not. Hartshorne's is slightly less general than the one given in EGA (see, e.g., http://user.math.uzh.ch/bruin/smooth.pdf pdf pp. 3/8), so (without trying to conjure up an example) I'd guess (*) is not always satisfied.

Comment: I don't have Hartshorne with me, but isn't it an exercise in that chapter to prove the equivalence? Maybe it's worded a little differently?

Comment: @Matt: Sorry, there's no exercise like that.

Comment: @Ramsey: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. Could you clarify please? A locally finite morphism $f$ of schemes can have the property of "having a relative dimension, equal to say n (necessarily a finite number)" which means that all the fibers of $f$ (at all points of the target) have the same dimension. The question is basically asking if that implies condition (*) in the situation of definition 2.

Comment: Hypothesis $(\ast)$ cannot be removed, as you can see via the special case when $Y={\rm{Spec}}(k)$ and $X={\rm{Spec}}(K)$ for a finite extension of fields. The $K$-vector space $\Omega^1_{X/Y}$ has some dimension $n≥0$, and $n>0$ if and only if $K/k$ is not separable (equivalently, not etale). So we need *some* condition to relate n to fiber dimensions. Hartshorne's $(\ast)$ is focusing exclusively on dimensions of generic fibers, so some work is needed to show that Definition 2 forces *all* fibers to have pure dimension $n$. Definition 1 is conceptually superior. 

Comment: The relative dimension of $f$ is a function on $Y$ (which is locally constant if $f$ is smooth in the EGA (or Milne) sense), but Hartshorne forces it to be globally constant on $Y$. In other words, a morphism of schemes of finite type over a field is smooth in the EGA sense if and only if it is locally smooth in the sense of Hartshorne. This means, for instance, that, according to Hartshorne's definition, a disjoint union of smooth schemes is not smooth, which is silly.

Comment: All I meant to say is that the two are defining different terms in the sense that Milne is defining "smooth" and Hartshorne "smooth of relative dimension $n$."  I.e. Hartshorne is building by name the relative dimension (implicit in Milne) into his definition, so he needs to say what it means.

Comment: @Denis: it's not smooth simply because it's outside the scope of his definition (which I do agree is silly).  But is there an instance to which both definitions apply for which the notions disagree?

Comment: @Denis, Ramsey: Good point. I see, there are a few things here. (1) You want to avoid including "relative dimension n" into the definition of smoothness, because then like Denis said, the property is no longer local on both domain and target (in particular, "smooth" and "smooth of relative dimension d" appear as two definitions in the stacks project).

Comment: Incidentally, the stacks project defines the "relative dimension" of a morphism, not a locally constant (in the smooth case) map to $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Denis: I see, when Milne (and as you say also EGA) says that "...is locally free of rank the relative dimension" they mean for the relative dimension to be interpreted not as a global property, but as the locally constant function (on the domain) (because the map is a priori smooth) you mention. If you repost this below, I'd be happy to accept this as an answer.

For reference, the article Benjamin mentions provides the local definition of relative dimension from EGA.

Comment: @LMN: The main content in relating the two definitions is as follows.  First, by flatness every irreducible component of $X$ dominates one of $Y$ and so under Def. 2 each generic fiber is of *pure* dimension $n$.  To prove the same for all *non-empty* fibers, by base change to dvr's over $Y$ and the purity hypothesis for the generic fibers we can pass to irreducible components (after the dvr base change, using the easy nature of flatness over a dvr!) to reduce to the case of an *irreducible* scheme fppf over a dvr. Now apply results about flatness and dimension theory (or EGA IV$_3$, 14.3.10).

Comment: @grp: Great proof! I love how you "descend" from special points to the generic point by using an intermediate dvr. Just do I know, when you say to base change over a dvr, I'm imagining that those dvrs come from the Krull-Akizuki theorem (and certainly those dvrs will do). Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: @LMN: Yes. When I was writing my comment about this argument I was planning to say "(the Krull-Akizuki trick)" but then I couldn't fit it all into one box, so I removed that phrase and hoped you would know the (standard) argument I had in mind for that step. 